# Display document value with new format in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

```
Companies
[
   { _id: 1, name: "Apple" },
   { _id: 2, name: "Microsoft" },
   { _id: 3, name: "Facebook" },
   { _id: 4, name: "Tesla" }
]
```

Is there a way to show `name` filed in query to new format?

Example )

```
Companies.find({}).newFormat(document => name: document.name[0] + '****')


Expected Result:

[
   { _id: 1, name: "A****" },
   { _id: 2, name: "M****" },
   { _id: 3, name: "F****" },
   { _id: 4, name: "T****" }
]
```

Comment: is it 4 * for every

Comment: are there any other fields or just name field?

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregate like this

```
db.Companies.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      name: {
        $concat: [
          { $substr: ['$name', 0, 1] }, 
          '****'
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do a projection with `$concat` and `$substr` with `find` as well

```js
db.collection.find({},{
  name: { $concat: [ { $substr: [ "$name", 0, 1 ] }, "****" ]}
})
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/M6I4P1Icfij)

if you want to add a variable number of "*" say based on the length of each name you can use `$reduce`

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      name: {
        $reduce: {
          input: { $range: [ 1, { $strLenCP: "$name" }, 1 ] },
          initialValue: { $substr: [ "$name", 0, 1 ] },
          in: { $concat: [ "$$value", "*" ] }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RwjYI5B94Um)